# Save or Download Javascript String as a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

I have an HTML string in javascript variable. I have to save/Download the string as a file on link click. It should be cross browser compatible.

I thought window.open with attachment Content-Disposition header, but not good solution because popup may be blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980569/open-a-save-file-dialog-for-a-js-variable), you could use downloadify: https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify. The client will need flash though.