# Using data URIs to prompt the user to save files

Tags: javascript, file, save, prompt, data-uri

I'm writing a web application which allows a user to select a `PNG` file, write an `iTXt` chunk to it and then save it back to their local file system. I would use the new `FileWriter` API to do so but currently only Google Chrome has added support for it.

Since my file is represented in memory as a [binary string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader#readAsBinaryString%28%29) I use data URIs to prompt the user to save the file as follows:

```
window.location.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + btoa(blob);
```

Since the mime-type is `application/octet-stream` the browser prompts the user to open or save it. However the problem is that the user does not know which type of file it is. So the user has to add the file extension manually.

Currently I alert the user which extension the file needs to be saved with. However this seems like an inelegant solution. Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Although it doesn't use a `data:` URI, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2980569/1468366) might have the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this were HTTP, then you'd either have to set the content disposition to attachment, to get the file saved even if its mime type is known, or to set the file name for an attachment of octet-stream type. Neither of these headers can be emulated using the [`data:` URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397), though, so I see no way to open a “Save as…” dialog using such a URI.

Others have asked how to [open a save file dialog for a js variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2980569/1468366), and judging from the answers there, there appears to be ready-to-use solutions which work as long as the client has Flash installed (and not blocked).

So perhaps you might try severl solutions, starting with the `FileWriter` you mention, trying a flash-based approach if that isn't available, and falling back to `data:` URI with an alert message about the file name extension. That way you could probably achieve the best result possible for each client.